# How to change the state of an UIButton in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uibutton

I have Objective-C working code for six buttons but I don't seem to find how to change the state of a button using Swift. So how do I make the following code work in Swift?

```
[self.button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button2_selected.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
button1.selected = NO;
button2.selected = !button2.selected;
button3.selected = NO;
button4.selected = NO;
button5.selected = NO;
button6.selected = NO;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check for this:

```
    var var_button_ =   UIButton()
    var_button_.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "button2_selected.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    var_button_.selected = false
    var_button_.selected = !var_button_.selected
    //var_button_.selected = true
```

Thanks 
BY JNYJ

Answer (score 4):

// You need to use the true and false for bool value in swift

### buttonOutletName.selected = true buttonOutletName.selected = false

// Create IBAction and check button selected or not in swift language.
You can change the button state.

```
@IBAction func favoriteButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

// Save Data
sender.selected  = !sender.selected;

if (sender.selected)
{
    NSLog(" Not Selected");
    sender.selected = false
    self.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked_checkbox"), forState: .Normal)

}
else
{
    NSLog(" Selected");
    sender.selected = false
       self.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox"), forState: .Normal)
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an outlet and an action for your button

Give 'button_selected' and 'button_not_selected' images for state configs Selected and Default respectively.

Then write the below code in the action,

```
if button.isSelected {
    button.isSelected = false
}
else {
    button.isSelected = true
}
```

I think this is the simplest way

Comment: The much simpler way would be: `button.isSelected = !button.isSelected`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1

Create `IBAction` and check button selected or not...There is no need to set `sender.selected` to true or false in the `if/else` statement.

```
@IBAction func rememberMe(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected  = !sender.selected
    if sender.selected {
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "RememberMe_Checkmark"), forState: .Normal)
        
    } else {
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "No_Checkmark"), forState: .Normal)
        
    }
    
}
```

#### Method 2

With Custom Type from Storyboard. See the Image Link to See Sample

[image]

From the Storyboard do the following

1. Change the Button type to "Custom"
2. Change the State Config to "Selected"
3. Set the Image to the Checkbox Icon with a checkmark asset
4. Set the Background to the Checkbox Icon without a checkmark asset

Create and IBAction from the Button and enter this single Line of Code

```
@IBAction func rememberMe(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected  = !sender.selected
}
```